# Android does PendingIntent die after performing action?

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

A simple question, but I cannot find an answer.
Is [Android PendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) still alive in system after performing it's action (sendBroadcast, startService etc.)?

If so, what is most efficient way to kill it - with [cancel()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#cancel()) or put [FLAG_ONE_SHOT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_ONE_SHOT) during creation?

Comment: "Is Android PendingIntent still alive in system after performing it's action" that would depend on whether or not anything is still holding onto it. "what is most efficient way to kill it - with cancel() or put FLAG_ONE_SHOT during creation?" -- off the cuff, if you are sure that you only need it once, use `FLAG_ONE_SHOT`. Otherwise, you need to figure out when and where you should call `cancel()`, which might be tricky depending on circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it.
@CommonsWare is right.
When I put `FLAG_ONE_SHOT` - `PendingIntent` kills itself after performing an action. But in such case I wasn't able to check if this `PendingIntent` is registered in system.

Finally I used `myPendingIntent.cancel()`.